# Java logic error: isPrime

Tags: java

Please  what  could  be the errors  in my  code and  why  is  it  printing  the  numbers  rather than  just  prime  numbers less than 10,000?

```
public class Isprime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The  prime  numbers  less  that  10000 are:");
        int number = 2;
        printprime(number);

    }

    public static void printprime(int number) {
        int pperline = 10;
        int count = 0;
        while (number < 10000) {
            if (isprime(number)) {
                count++;
            }
            if (count % pperline == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.print(number + ",");
            }
            number++;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isprime(int number) {
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number / 2; divisor++) {
            if (number % divisor == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Either indent the `return false` in `isprime` or add brackets: `if (number%divisor==0) { return false; }`.

Comment: I think you want that `if-else` clause to be inside the `if` clause there.  Also, You're currently not printing the number at all if count is divisible by 10

Comment: @soong good catch, I didn't see that at first.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating whether a number is prime or not just fine, but you aren't doing your print inside the condition that checks for that.  This means your count of primes is correct, but you print something for every number, not just the prime ones.

You need to move your print statements inside your `if (isprime(number))` check.  Also, you are only print a prime *or* a newline.  You should remove the `else` from your format logic so that you don't skip printing every 10th prime number:

```
public static void printprime(int number) {
    int pperline = 10;
    int count = 0;
    while (number < 10000) {
        if (isprime(number)) {
            count++;
            if (count % pperline == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.print(number + ",");
        }
        number++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you indent your code properly:

```
public static void printprime(int number) {
    int pperline = 10;
    int count = 0;
    while(number < 10000){
        if(isprime(number)){
            count++;
        }
        if (count % pperline == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(number+",");
        }
        number++;
    }
}
```

You can see that it will print every number unless you've chosen to print a newline instead.

Move the ending brace for `if(isPrime(number))` after the `if`/`else`.  Also, you'll want to print the prime regardless of whether you need to print a newline, so move the print of the number outside of the `else` (and get rid of the `else`).

```
public static void printprime(int number) {
    int pperline = 10;
    int count = 0;
    while(number < 10000) {
        if(isprime(number)) {
            count++;
            if (count % pperline == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.print(number+",");
        }
        number++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error came from your first "if". Try to put something in the brackets {}

Comment: Please be a little more specific in your answer. What are you expecting to see in the bracket? This will help the person determine if your answer is a possible solution to their problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may find my solution helpful so I'm posting it :)

```
public class Isprime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The  prime  numbers  less  that  10000 are:\n");
        int number = 2;
        printprime(number);
    }

    public static void printprime(int number) {
        int pperline = 10;
        int count = 0;
        while (number < 10000) {
            if (isprime(number)) {
                count++;
                System.out.print(number + ", "); // consider printing out if and only if
                                                // the number is actually a prime
                                                // your solution is more complicated and you
                                                // also miss some else if statement
                if (count % pperline == pperline - 1) { // results from above approach, now we are printing endline after
                                                        // every 10 numbers
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            number++;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isprime(int number) {
        // note that:
        // 1) one is not a prime
        // 2) you can easily prove that you don't have to check all the divisors up to number / 2
        // you can optimize your code a bit by checking divisors up to the square root of number
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor * divisor <= number; divisor++) {
            if (number % divisor == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return number >= 2; // checks if number was negative (negatives are not prime, 0 and 1 are also not prime)
    }

}
```